# how to use select2 in angularjs to have string value instead of an object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have data as :

```
selected  : { id : <string,a task id>, description = <string> };

tasks = [ {  id : 'a', value : 'Apple' }, { id : 'b', value : 'Ball' }, 
// more items;
];
```

now i want to use select2 such as variable bind to select2 should contain only the id, not the whole object

so if i select Ball, the `selected` should be `{ id : 'b', description : 'some_desc' }`

```
<ui-select ng-model="selected.id">
            <ui-select-match placeholder="select name ">{{ $select.selected.value }}</ui-select-match>
            <ui-select-choices repeat="type in tasks | filter: $select.search">{{type.value}}</ui-select-choices>
          </ui-select>
```

How do i achieve to have only string as selected value not the whole object.

EDIT : here is the example plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/onmP7FKIa7MpXsRnH025?p=preview

In which selected.sel is an object not a string.
i want selected.sel should be a string always that is the code of conntry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use in your repeat:

```
country.code as country in countries
```

should do the trick.

from your [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Oo0ZplzT3YMzM2XacxSb?p=preview)

```
<ui-select ng-model="selected.sel">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select or search a country...">
      {{$select.selected.name}}
    </ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="country.code as country in countries | filter: $select.search">
       <span ng-bind-html="country.name | highlight: $select.search"></span>
       <small ng-bind-html="country.code | highlight: $select.search"></small>
    </ui-select-choices>
 </ui-select>
```

and if not, you should switch to the new [ui-select](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select) directive, since select2 would be discontinued.